# Is it possible to add ODataController controller to an MVC web app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have an existing asp.net MVC 5 web application. I do not want to crate a separate project for asp.net webapi OData and I want re-use www domain of the web app for OData app. I'd like to add some ODataControllers to that MVC web application to be consumed in some cshttml view pages with flexible, robust queries. Is it possible to do that? If so, how is about the routing configs must be updated for web app routes and OData routes? Thank you.